# Как правильно говорить: "часы" или "пара часов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: **Часы** или **пара часов**?

Answer (score 2):

Следует говорить: одни брюки (об одном предмете) или двое брюк, две штуки брюк (о двух предметах).

В просторечии выражение пара брюк часто заменяет собой именно общеупотребительное одни брюки. Это вызвано аналогией с общеупотребительными словосочетаниями, такими, как пара сапог, пара носков, пара перчаток – о двух предметах, используемых в качестве пары.
Употребления словосочетания пара брюк также нежелательно в связи с тем, что это словосочетание может быть по-разному понято собеседниками (один будет считать, что речь идет об одном предмете, другой – что говорится о двух предметах). 
Употребление слова пара в роли счетного слова нормативно, только когда речь идет о парных предметах (пара ботинок, пара перчаток, пара весел и т. п.). 
Употребление слова пара в значении "несколько" (пару лет работать над проектом, отсюда до станции пара километров, выполнить пару заданий, выйти на пару минут, пара пустяков) или "две штуки чего-либо непарного" (пара яблок, пара мешков) характеризуется словарями русского языка как просторечное.

Comment: Community подтолкнула посмотреть, и мне показалось, что в Вашем ответе всё-таки не хватает заключения для полноты: что же делать с часами-то?

Answer (score 0):

Часы (если одни) или двое часов.

Comment: Не понимаю ни вопрос, ни этот ответ. *Двое часов* — это о чём вообще?

Comment: *Двое часов — это о чём вообще?* - это о *двоих* часах. которые прибор для времени. Будильниках, там, курантах, наручных...  Вопрос - да, непонятен. Но ответ - грамотный. Может, не от того вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Фразу можно целиком посмотреть? А то непонятно, какой контекст может подобный вопрос вызвать. Это совершенно разные вещи.

Хотя "пара часов" в любом случае возможно только в сниженной речи и означает "примерно два часа". 
Вообще в отношении "пары" при предметах, имеющих только множественное число (ворота, брюки и т. п.) есть неписанный запрет на нормативное применение вне особых контекстов. Ибо возникает путаница типа "пара брюк" - это двое одинаковых штанов или две штанины одного предмета "брюки". Филологи, возможно, будут настаивать на первом, а народ - скорее будет за последнее. Поскольку "пара" - это объекты, дополняющие друг друга и составляющие единое целое, а не просто "два штука брук".